# How do I search set of keywords from keywords field in Solr?

Tags: apache, syntax, solr

So I have a keyword field with this schema
Indexed, Tokenized, Multivalued, TermVector Stored, Omit Norms

then I wanna search set of keywords against it like

q=keyword:keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, etc, etc

and want to return most matching keywords, even 1 match keyword is fine, but ordered by most match.

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
q=keyword:(keyword1 OR keyword2 OR keyword3 OR...)
```

Solr will give a higher score to the documents that match more keywords so they will be the first results. You can see the assigned score by appending `&fl=*,score` to your querystring.

Comment: ahhh, that was simple. I was expecting like some sort of settings in the server for keyword field but this is what i want.
Thanks!